# How to reference stdin as an option in a program in a pipeline?

Tags: bash, stdin

I have a program that outputs a file that I want to use as stdin for the next program. However, program2 has "-in" and "-out" options that want filenames. So if I'm piping into program2, how can I reference the stdin for the "-in" option?

```
program1 | program2 -in stdin -out filename
```

Answer (score 4):

If `program2` doesn't use its stdin by itself and `-in` is the only way to specify the input file, these are useful options:

- `/dev/stdin` or `/proc/fd/0` or `/proc/self/fd/0` (if available; kernel feature, not required by POSIX)

  ```
    program1 | program2 -in /dev/stdin -out filename
  ```
- Process substitution (supported in Bash and few other shells, not required by POSIX)

  ```
    program2 -in <(program1) -out filename
  ```
- Named fifo (POSIX way)

  ```
    mkfifo foo
    program1 >foo &   # in background
    program2 -in foo -out filename
    rm fifo
  ```

Note that many programs that don't normally use their stdin, behave this way for a reason: they need the input file to be seekable. With `<bar program2` you can make the file descriptor 0 of `program2` point to the `bar` file which is seekable, but in general stdin is not seekable, so such programs don't bother using it. Each of the above methods may make your program fail if it expects the file to be seekable.

Comment: I'd recommend /dev/stdin instead of /proc/[self]/fd/0 -- it's not required by POSIX either, but it seems to be much more widely supported than /proc. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36403/how-portable-are-dev-stdin-dev-stdout-and-dev-stderr) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/338667/unix-systems-without-dev-stdin-dev-stdout-and-dev-stderr).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
program1 > stdin & program2 -in stdin -out filename
```

This is not a pipe actually but will put all the stdout of program1 inside stdin file so then program2 can read it.

Alternatively some programs use the shorthand - when they attempt to read/write from shell. So it may be like:

```
program1 | program2 -in - -out filename
```

Answer (score 1):

The following syntax should work in shell by pointing input file to a special file [`/dev/stdin`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/stdin):

```
program1 | program2 -in /dev/stdin -out filename
```